# Set gid bit not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, setgid

I have these permissions on a folder.

```
drwxr-sr-x  2 root    sharedmaster  4096 2010-09-22 10:36 rantest99
```

I have user tony which is in the group sharedmaster.  When I try to mkdir from tony it says permission denied. Why is that?

I have set the gid bit on directory so that new directory has group read write permissions.  Where am I wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition granting [write access](https://serverfault.com/questions/183403/set-gid-bit-not-working/183412#183412) on the parent directory you almost certainly need to adjust the umask of the user which is probably set to filter away group/other write access.

You probably want to set a umask of 0002.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to `chmod g+w rantest99`.

**Edit:**

`chmod g+w dirname` makes a directory writable by members of the group. This is what `chmod g+s dirname` does:

From `info coreutils 'Directory Setuid and Setgid'`

> 27.4 Directories and the Set-User-ID and Set-Group-ID Bits
> ==========================================================
>
> On most systems, if a directory's set-group-ID bit is set, newly
> created subfiles inherit the same group as the directory, and newly
> created subdirectories inherit the set-group-ID bit of the parent
> directory.  On a few systems, a directory's set-user-ID bit has a
> similar effect on the ownership of new subfiles and the set-user-ID
> bits of new subdirectories.  These mechanisms let users share files
> more easily, by lessening the need to use 'chmod' or 'chown' to share
> new files.

Comment: chmod g+w give write access to group sharedmaster. mkdir need only read access

Comment: I have set  chmod g+s on the directory parent to rantest99 and i tested making directory rantest99. But the i was not able to write anything inside the newly cretaed directory . although it has s bit set. what is the diff between g+s and g+w

Comment: @Master, you are also going to need to set/adjust the user's umask.

Comment: @binbn: `mkdir somedir; id -Gn someuser | grep somegroup; sudo chown root:somegroup somedir; sudo -u someuser mkdir somedir/subdir` "mkdir: cannot create directory `somedir/subdir': Permission denied" `sudo chmod g+w somedir; sudo -u someuser mkdir somedir/subdir` *success*

Comment: @Master: See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

paste error please.

```
test@u1004s02:/tmp$ ls -ald 1
drwxr-sr-x 2 root test 4096 Sep 22 05:49 1
test@u1004s02:/tmp$ id
uid=1001(test) gid=1001(test) groups=1001(test)
test@u1004s02:/tmp$ cd 1  
test@u1004s02:/tmp/1$
```

About setgid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories